# How select a range of row in pandas dataframe determined by str value in a specific column, " Every Time this str value appear i need a new slice"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like :

```
        lati      longi     Report        Time         Video name
0         XXX        YYY      ZZZ        0:00:00        AAA
1         XXX        YYY      ZZZ        0:00:01        AAA
2         XXX        YYY      ZZZ        0:00:02        AAA
3         XXX        YYY      ZZZ        0:00:03        AAA
4         XXX        YYY      ZZZ        0:00:00        AAA
5         XXX        YYY      ZZZ        0:00:01        AAA
6         XXX        YYY      ZZZ        0:00:02        AAA
7         XXX        YYY      ZZZ        0:00:03        AAA
8         XXX        YYY      ZZZ        0:00:00        AAA
9         XXX        YYY      ZZZ        0:00:00        AAA
```

I need change the value of Column "Video name", when the value of column Time is
equal = 0:00:00 until the next Column Time = 0:00:00. So every time i find the 0:00:00 the Video name will change.

And the Video names I will get in a list

list_video_name=['AAA','BBB','DDD']

My desire final dataframe is:

```
        lati      longi     Report        Time         Video name
0         XXX        YYY      ZZZ        0:00:00        AAA
1         XXX        YYY      ZZZ        0:00:01        AAA
2         XXX        YYY      ZZZ        0:00:02        AAA
3         XXX        YYY      ZZZ        0:00:03        AAA
4         XXX        YYY      ZZZ        0:00:00        BBB
5         XXX        YYY      ZZZ        0:00:01        BBB
6         XXX        YYY      ZZZ        0:00:02        BBB
7         XXX        YYY      ZZZ        0:00:03        BBB
8         XXX        YYY      ZZZ        0:00:00        DDD
9         XXX        YYY      ZZZ        0:00:01        DDD
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
m = df["Time"].eq("0:00:00").cumsum()
df["Video name"] = ((m != m.shift()).cumsum() + 64).apply(lambda x: chr(x) * 3)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  lati longi Report     Time Video name
0  XXX   YYY    ZZZ  0:00:00        AAA
1  XXX   YYY    ZZZ  0:00:01        AAA
2  XXX   YYY    ZZZ  0:00:02        AAA
3  XXX   YYY    ZZZ  0:00:03        AAA
4  XXX   YYY    ZZZ  0:00:00        BBB
5  XXX   YYY    ZZZ  0:00:01        BBB
6  XXX   YYY    ZZZ  0:00:02        BBB
7  XXX   YYY    ZZZ  0:00:03        BBB
8  XXX   YYY    ZZZ  0:00:00        CCC
9  XXX   YYY    ZZZ  0:00:01        CCC
```

Comment: what If my Video name is is on a list ? What a i need change ? And why +64 ? Thx

Comment: @VitorBento Can you please edit your question and put there sample data and expected output?

Comment: @VitorBento If you want to get unique video names, you can run `df["Video name"].unique().tolist()` afterwards.